# Remove duplicates from array_agg, where elements are also arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, array-agg

In a Postgres 11 database, I've got two arrays in two views which are joined to MAIN table:

vw_ideas_role_direction_mappings.user_direction_id - array (like {101,103,} or {101,103} or {101,} or {101,,,,104})
vw_ideas_role_category_mappings.user_direction_id - array like previous.

**DDL of view vw_ideas_role_category_mappings:**

category_id - int8
user_direction_id - array
-- no constraints

**DDL of view vw_ideas_role_direction_mappings:**

direction_id  - int8
user_direction_id - array
-- no constraints

**DDL table idea:**

id - bigserial
-- no constraints

And the following query, where I join everything:

```
SELECT i.id,
         array_agg(dvircm.user_direction_id || dvirdm.user_direction_id) AS directions_id
           FROM idea.ideas i
             LEFT JOIN vw_ideas_role_direction_mappings  = i.direction_id
             LEFT JOIN vw_ideas_role_category_mappings dvircm ON dvircm.category_id  = i.category_id
GROUP BY i.id
```

So there can be NULL in arrays and duplicates.

This query does not remove them and further more it throws error - cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality (maybe because there are commas ' , ' in arrays before or after digits? Because when I create array user_direction_id I use this query

```
array_agg(distinct vw_user_data_all_roles.direction_id))
```

How to get rid of the error and remove duplicates and null after combining 2 arrays?

Comment: What do you mean "there are commas in arrays" - do you have empy/null elements in your arrays? Why do you not always have exactly two elements and what do you think PostgreSQL should be doing when they differ?

Comment: Start by providing the (relevant parts of) exact table definitions showing data types and constraints as `CREATE TABLE` scripts; and always your version of Postgres. Do you need to preserve any particular order? Do you need to preserve NULL values from original arrays?

Comment: I've redone description.  Can you check it again?

Comment: What's the exact data type of your arrays? `text[]`or `int[]`? This is not a valid array literal: `{101,103,}` ...

Comment: It's text[].  Because source table has type - text on column direction_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this would do what you want:

```sql
SELECT i.id, sub.directions_id
FROM   idea.ideas i
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM   vw_ideas_role_direction_mappings d, unnest(d.user_direction_id) u(id)
      WHERE  d.direction_id = i.direction_id
      AND    u.id IS NOT NULL
      UNION
      SELECT u.id
      FROM   vw_ideas_role_category_mappings c, unnest(c.user_direction_id) u(id)
      WHERE  c.category_id  = i.category_id
      AND    u.id IS NOT NULL
      )
   ) sub(directions_id) ON sub.directions_id <> '{}';  -- exclude empty array?
```

`UNION` after unnesting removes duplicate array elements.
NULL values are removed.

About the ARRAY constructor:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Since the ARRAY constructor always returns a row (like an aggregate function), we can use `CROSS JOIN`. Else, we'd use `LEFT JOIN .. ON true`. About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If you need to preserve some original order, consider `WITH ORDINALITY` and `ORDER BY` ... See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Wow. Works great! Can you advice how to make this {,9,101} in output into {9,101} ?
What should I add?

Comment: @Gerzzog: I updated with a version that removes NULL elements